# Center Java splash screen on multi-monitor

Tags: java, position, splash-screen, multiple-monitors

I'm creating a splash screen for a Java application using the SplashScreen class. The problem is that the position on multi-monitor systems is undefined. The documentation states "the position on multi-monitor systems is not specified - it is platform and implementation dependent". The application is going to be used solely on multi-monitor platforms, and I would like to ensure that it's always centered on one of the screens. Is there any way to achieve this? The application is going to be used on Linux only, so the platform is the same everywhere.

Comment: The built-in splash screen is displayed by "before the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) starts". You're not going to be able to affect its position. *btad* has a reasonable answer, but note my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a sample Javafx equivalent of Splash screen. However this splash screen is basically a java swing applet that is called from javafx to be displayed to the user and simulates more or less eclipse and netbeans splash screen using progress bar and titles for the loaded contents.

Following is the link at 
http://0divides0.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/splash-screen-with-javafx/

You must be able to get the code and seperate out the splash screen code written in java swings and use it for yourself.

This is a custom java swing splash screen. 
and hence to center the splash screen it uses the traditional functions

```
 Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 Dimension labelSize = l.getPreferredSize();
 setLocation(screenSize.width / 2 - (labelSize.width / 2), screenSize.height / 2 - (labelSize.height / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Then don't use the builtin splash screen from Java 6. Create your own splash screen using your UI toolkit and position the window manually by calculating its size and the size of the available screens.

Comment: I have tried this, and it works as long as I load the splash screen in a separate thread before I start creating the rest of my GUI. However, the last line of the code that loads my GUI breaks this. I invoke KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
   .setGlobalCurrentFocusCycleRoot(pane); to make "pane" the focus cycle root, which I have to. But as soon as this line is added to the end of my GUI building code, the splash screen is only displayed as a gray square. That's why I aimed for the SplashScreen class instead (which I guess should be best practice to use anyway).

Comment: I think you can't get around when using the built-in splash screen. This is one of the disadvantages of the interoperability of a Java solution working on all OSes.

But have you considered using SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() in order to serialize GUI creation and processing for setting the splash screen upfront. There is also a couple of tutorials available howto create a AWT/Swing/etc. based splash screen.
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip104.html
http://www.randelshofer.ch/oop/javasplash/javasplash.html
etc.

Comment: First: *do not manage swing components "in a separate thread."* They are meant to be updated only from the event dispatch thread, and you're probably getting the gray box for just this reason.

Comment: Second: splash screens are meant to cover the application startup time. Back when Java was used for applets, over a 56k modem, most of this startup time was spent downloading classes. In that world, a splash-screen loaded before the JVM makes a lot of sense. In today's world, it makes much more sense to create your own undecorated splash frame as soon as the app starts; the load time for basic Swing classes is a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

An other sample code :

```
 // Get the size of the screen
 Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 // Determine the new location of the window
 int w = login.getSize().width;
 int h = login.getSize().height;
 int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
 int y = (dim.height-h)/2;
 // Move the window
 setLocation(x, y);
 setVisible(true);
```

Comment: No need to calculate that much. As soon as the JWindow or undecorated JFrame is packed, a call to setLocationRelativeTo(null) will center it on the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be defined in the context of Java, but it's for sure defined in the context of the display server.

For Linux / X11 the important aspect is whether [XInerama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) is enabled or not.  This X extension enables applications to get knowledge of the physical displays that comprise the desktop.

A quick way of verifying that XInerama is enabled is to try to maximize a window on your multi monitor target system.  With XInerama enabled it should only maximize to the dimensions of the active monitor, not the entire screen surface.

Splash screens will when XInerama is enabled be centered on the active monitor as the application launches.

If you focus solely on getting your application's splash screen positioned correctly you will quickly get feedback on other multi monitor issues like for instance the task bar stretching across all screens or windows that maximize across all screens.

Comment: This is not true. According to your test Xinerama is active on my desktop, yet the splash screen is centered such that it is 50% on each of the two screens.

Comment: The problem is more in the JDK as the splash screen is centered wrongly, but a call to JFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null) will position it in the center of the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution to center a frame on a screen:

```
    GraphicsConfiguration c = frm.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle in = c.getBounds();

    int center_x = in.x + in.width / 2;
    int center_y = in.y + in.height / 2;

    frm.setLocation(center_x - frm.getWidth()/2, center_y - frm.getHeight()/2);
```

With the accepted solution I had the problem that the frame was displayed at the border of my two screens. i.e. at the center of both screens.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. But there is no need to calculate that much. As soon as the JWindow or undecorated JFrame is packed, a call to setLocationRelativeTo(null) will center it on the first screen.